# Funny books about Etymology and grammar in Spanish language

Tags: etimología

Are there funny Spanish  books about the etymology of words, like "Word perfect" by Susie Dent for English etymology, or "have you eaten your grandma" by Gyles Brandreth for English grammar?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Una posibilidad que sugiero es *Palabrotalogía: Etimologías de las palabras soeces*, de Virgilio Ortega. Como lo dice el título, está centrado en analizar las etimologías de las malas palabras; aunque también aparecen otras que no son actualmente ‘malas’.

También el mismo autor ha publicado otro libro más abarcativo que se llama *Palabralogía: Un apasionante viaje por el origen de las palabras*, el estilo es parecido aunque dudo que te haga reír tanto como el primero que mencioné.